# MySQL timestamp and GROUP BY with two tables

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with 3 fields:

- `ID` (not unique, not primary key)
- `timestamp`
- `marker`

I want to get the last entry for every distinct `ID`, but when I do
`SELECT ID, max(timestamp) from table GROUP BY ID`
the marker field is wrong.

I have another table with the following fields:

- `ID` (unique, primary key)
- `lat`
- `lng`

I would like to perform the same query but with the `lat` and `lng` fields as well, but since I can't do the first step, I don't know what kind of query should I use. I've been trying with no success.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/sql-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/sql-fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299556/sql-group-by-max, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109941/querying-for-a-unique-value-based-on-the-aggregate-of-another-value-while-groupin, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723054/extra-fields-with-sql-min-group-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an `ID` column that is not unique sounds "unexpected", but this one should get you the expected rows:

```
SELECT t.id, t.timestamp, MAX( t.marker ) marker,
       t2.lat, t2.lng
FROM table t
JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(timestamp) ts
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id
) tx ON ( tx.id = t.id AND tx.ts = t.timestamp )
JOIN t2 ON ( t2.id = tx.id )
GROUP BY t.id, t.timestamp
```

The second group by will make sure that you only get one row in case there are more records for the same `id` and `timestamp`.

**Update**: Edited query to join `t2`.

Use `LEFT JOIN` in case there are `id`s in `t1` that do not exist in `t2`. `lat` and `lng` would then be `NULL` for that rows.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your answer. The reason ID is not unique in the table is because I need all the entries for all the transactions a client ID does.

I'll test your query once at home. How could join it to a second table table2 that has the same IDs (but unique) to get its lat and lng fields that are only in this second table?

Thanks

Comment: @charo: Edited my answer to add columns from `t2`.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'm willing to test it at home :)

Comment: In that case you should `accept` my answer. You could up-vote it too, but that's your decision of course :)